# Angular - show specific number of checkboxes in a row

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4 to create a form. One of the controls in the form is a list of checkboxes.

Please refer to Plnkr [Plnkr - Working](https://plnkr.co/edit/scuOPsypxP8IEsW8Vb2L?p=preview)

The list of stations is fetched from a webservice. For simplicity, I have hard coded the Stations array. For each of these stations, I would like to display a checkbox (under 'station' formgroup, so that all selected stations can be submitted under the 'station' formgroup). This Plnkr does what it's expected to do, that is display one checkbox for every station.

However, I would like to have some control over how the checkboxes are rendered. Right now, each checkbox is in a row of it's own. I would like to display, lets say, 5 checkboxes per row.

Since doing this in HTML was turning out to be very complicated, I decided to convert the stations array to a 2D array and then iterate over the 2D array in HTML to show 5 checkboxes per row.

This is the Plnk for the 2D array attempt                                        [2D Plnkr - not working](https://plnkr.co/edit/isgEDDI4H5s41tcUrIEO?p=preview)

```
<table>
            <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary" formGroupName="station" 
              *ngFor="let station of stations2D; let i = index">
              <tr>
              <td><input id="{{ station[i][0] }}" formControlName="{{station[i][0] }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station[i][0]}}</td>
              <td><input id="{{ station[i][0] }}" formControlName="{{station[i][1] }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station[i][1]}}</td>
              <td><input id="{{ station[i][0] }}" formControlName="{{station[i][2] }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station[i][2]}}</td>
              <td><input id="{{ station[i][0] }}" formControlName="{{station[i][3] }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station[i][3]}}</td>
              <td><input id="{{ station[i][0] }}" formControlName="{{station[i][4] }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station[i][4]}}</td>
            </tr>
            </div>
            </table>
```

This is not working. While checkboxes are displayed, there are no labels and there are a bunch of errors in console stating 'Cannot find control'.
What am I doing wrong in setting the controls? Is this approach even valid, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a simple css class to line break after every five stations. No need to create 2D array for it.

css:

```
.five-a-row{ 
   float:left;
   display:table-column;
   width:20%;
}

.main-box{
   width: 100%;
}
```

[Edited plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YlWwQ6WpB78ywijWMGQ8?p=preview)

Comment: This is awesome, I didn't realize it was possible to do it using CSS. However, there is one issue that I can see. The checkboxes are not aligned properly one below the other. For instance, checkbox for StationJ is to the left of checkbox for StationE, which doesn't look very neat. I would like checkboxes for StationJ, StationE and StationO to be aligned one below the other. Same for other checkboxes which happen to be in the same column.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check the uppated code and demo

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is to handle it using the Slice Pipe that Angular provides. [Here is the working plunker for your code.](https://embed.plnkr.co/xsg7hT16tq5jZya9qeOf/) I have made the code to divide 4 checkboxes per row.

The way to do is to decide the total number of rows in component side and then add slice pipe to handle the rest of the functionality.

Inside component do this:

```
public rows:Array<any> = [];
public numElement = 4; // No of elements per Row
```

inside your ngOnInit do this:

```
this.rows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.stations.length / this.numElement)).keys());
```

And inside your HTML use the Slice pipe like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let r of rows" style="display:flex;">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary col-md-3" style="float:left;" formGroupName="station" 
              *ngFor="let station of stations | slice:(r*numElement):(numElement*(r+1));">
              <input id="{{ station }}" formControlName="{{station }}" type="checkbox" [checked]=false> {{station}}
            </div>
            </div>
```